# Firebase token is null when I run the app for the first time

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-sharedpreferences

I'm trying to retrieve a firebase token, but when I ran the app for the first time, the firebase token was null. I don't know why. When I ran the app for the second time I got the token. I saw another post with a similar question but I didn't understand it.

This is my code :

```
public class MyFirebaseInstanceIDService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {
private static final String LOGTAG = "android-fcm";

@Override
public void onTokenRefresh() {
    String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();

    storeTokenInPref(refreshedToken);

}


private void storeTokenInPref(String token) {
    SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
    editor.putString("regId", token);
    editor.apply();
}
```

I have a fragment where you can get the token of preferences, and then I want to compare if token is inside the database.

```
public class Profile extends Fragment implements MainActivity.OnBackPressedListener{

private View view;

private  SharedPreferences preferences;

private String token;

private static final String LOGTAG = "android-fcm";

public Profile(){}

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.profile, container, false);

    ((MainActivity) getActivity()).setOnBackPressedListener(this);

    preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getContext());

    displayFirebaseToken();
    return view;
}

private void displayFirebaseToken() {

    token = preferences.getString("regId", null);
    Log.e(LOGTAG, "Firebase reg id: " + token);

    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(token)) {

        SQLiteHelper database = new SQLiteHelper(getActivity(), "DB", null, 1);

        List<Beacon> beaconList = database.getAllBeacons();

        String classroom = "";

        for (int i = 0; i < beaconList.size(); i++) {

            if (beaconList.get(i).getId().equals(token)) {
                classroom = beaconList.get(i).getClassroom();
                break;
            }
        }
        classroomTextView.setText(classroom);

    }else {
        System.out.println("Firebase token is not received yet!");
    }
}
```

Comment: It is possible to receive a null token when calling `getToken()` (see the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client#retrieve-the-current-registration-token)).
So it is highly possible that the token is still being generated the first time you run your app. In your post, you already have `onTokenRefresh()` implemented. Could you verify if it is called after calling `getToken()` for sometime? If it does, then this should just be the intended behavior.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because onTokenRefresh() and storeTokenInPref() have not been called yet by the time that you are trying to use the value in displayFirebaseToken(). You need to wait with using the token until it is available. In general there is no hard rule how long that will take, as it depends on factors like network connectivity.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
private void displayFirebaseToken() {

token = preferences.getString("regId", null);
if(token==null)
token = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
Log.e(LOGTAG, "Firebase reg id: " + token);

if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(token)) {

    SQLiteHelper database = new SQLiteHelper(getActivity(), "DB", null, 1);

    List<Beacon> beaconList = database.getAllBeacons();

    String classroom = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < beaconList.size(); i++) {

        if (beaconList.get(i).getId().equals(token)) {
            classroom = beaconList.get(i).getClassroom();
            break;
        }
    }
    classroomTextView.setText(classroom);

}else {
    System.out.println("Firebase token is not received yet!");
}
```

Since you are trying to get saved the device token by method onTokenRefresh() which is not called till the token will be refreshed you need to get it manually using `

```
FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
```

by using this snippet of code you can get your device token any where in your app

`